# Javascript - Store variable as object and function

Tags: javascript, variables, object

I've seen instances of a variable being both an object and a string. Example:

```js
alert(x + ""); // Hello
alert(x()); // World
```

This kind of thing is what jQuery does with the `$` variable.

How might you get this effect?

Comment: You don't use jQuery's `$` like in your first example. jQuery's `$` is simply a function which also has properties (which might be functions themselves). The `toString` mentioned in the answers is rarely useful to override.

Comment: Are you sure that's what jQuery does? Last time I looked, many (most?) of its methods are overloaded and do stuff depending on whether they are passed a Function, Object, string, whatever, rather than overwriting or replacing built–in methods.

Comment: Also, jQuery does *not* override `toString` (despite it not being useful anyway). You can see that by simply opening the console on SO and typing `$.toString()` or make sure via `$.toString === Function.prototype.toString`, which comes out `true`.

Comment: jQuery allows you to do `$.xyz();` or `$(".abc").xyz();`. That's what I was talking about.

Comment: @tupperkion any function can have properties, because functions are objects.

Comment: So basically you can have `function x() { return "hello"; } x.world = function() { return "world"; } alert(x() + " " + x.world());` and that would alert `hello world`. I see now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a variable can't be both an object and a (primitive) string.

However, if you attempt to convert an object to a string (e.g. using `obj + ''`), the string returned by its `toString` method is used instead.

```
function x() {
    return "World";
}
x.toString = function() {
    return "Hello";
};
```

Comment: And *vice versa*, primitives are converted to Objects for the sake of evaluation of expressions: `'blah'.split()`. ;-)